# Why is the foreach loop NOT making a change to the file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I am reviewing a nodeJS program someone wrote to merge objects from two files and write the data to a mongodb.  I am struggling to wrap my head around how this is working - although I ran it and it works perfectly.
It lives here: https://github.com/muhammad-asad-26/Introduction-to-NodeJS-Module3-Lab

To start, there are two JSON files, each containing an array of 1,000 objects which were 'split apart' and are really meant to be combined records. The goal is to merge the 1st object of both files together, and then both 2nd objects ...both 1,000th objects in each file, and insert into a db.

Here are the excerpts that give you context:

```
const customerData = require('./data/m3-customer-data.json')
const customerAddresses = require('./data/m3-customer-address-data.json')

mongodb.MongoClient.connect(url, (error, client) => {

    customerData.forEach((element, index) => {
        element = Object.assign(element, customerAddresses[index])
        //I removed some logic which decides how many records to push to the DB at once
        var tasks = [] //this array of functions is for use with async, not relevant
        tasks.push((callback) => {


            db.collection('customers').insertMany(customerData.slice(index, recordsToCopy), (error, results) => {
                callback(error)
            });
        });

    })
})
```

As far as I can tell,
element = Object.assign(element, customerAddresses[index])
is modifying the current element during each iteration - IE the JSON object in the source file

to back this up,
db.collection('customers').insertMany(**customerData**.slice(index, recordsToCopy)
further seems to confirm that when writing the completed merged data to the database the author is reading out of that original customerData file - which makes sense only if the completed merged data is living there.

Since the source files are unchanged, the two things that are confusing me are, in order of importance:

**1)Where does the merged data live** before being written to the db?  The customerData file is unchanged at the end of runtime.

2)What's it called when you access a JSON file using array syntax?  I had no idea you could read files without the functionality of the fs module or similar.  The author read files using only require('filename'). I would like to read more about that.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: @CertainPerformance I just ran it again and confirmed - customerData file unchanged, the db 'test' has  been created with collection "customers" with the successfully merged records.

Comment: Pretty sure `require` will *only read* the file (and put the parsed JSON string -> object into memory under the variable name `customerData`), but since it never stringifies and saves it later, the `.json` file remains unchanged.

Comment: This json locally import feature was implemented in version 8.5.0 is so old, I even adopted this kind of import since I started using node which was in April / 2018.
[DOC](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require); [Release Date](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/)

Comment: Thanks for the Docs link, I had read that but it doesn't elaborate on how the file is treated by the program - read to memory as CertainPerformance suggested, and modified only in memory...?  I'm happy to read docs, I just need some direction on where to start.

Comment: Yes certain this is correct in memory, in the documentation in require it mentions the require.cache and just below a mention is made to objects. Basically importing modules are constructor objects, it becomes clearer because in code it uses the Object.assign () method to retrieve the values. The good way would be to start by reading the documentation of the [constructor objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) that shows us how to manipulate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Question 1:**

The merged data lives in the `customerData` variable before it's sent to the database. It exists only in memory at the time `insertMany` is called, and is passed in as a parameter. There is no reason for anything on the file system to be overwritten -- in fact it would be inefficient to modify that `.json` file every time you called the database -- storing that information is the job of the database, not a file within your application. *If* you wanted to overwrite the file, it would be easy enough -- just add something like `fs.writeFile('./data/m3-customer-data.json', JSON.stringify(customerData), 'utf8', console.log('overwritten'));` after the `insertMany`. Be sure to include `const fs = require('fs');`. To make it clearer what is happening, try writing the value of `customerData.length` to the file instead.

**Question 2:**
Look at the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require) on `require()` in Node. All it's doing is parsing the data in the JSON file.

There's no magic here. A static json file is parsed to an array using require and stored in memory as the `customerData` variable. Its values are manipulated and sent to another computer elsewhere where it can be stored. As the code was originally written, the only purpose that json file serves is to be read.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time!  It's crystal clear now!